# Grouping dates in a row from blank to blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on to group different dates into start and end date format with changing the start date every time there is a blank in between the data

I have tried different formulas like concatenate, substitute, isblank but not able to find an answer.

TO explain further: If I have a date in A and continue till D without blank, that will be my first group starting from A and ending at D. Similarly, if I have date in A and then another one in C so my first group will be A itself both start and end and second group will be C both start and end.

Also, the data I shared is a demo data, I have thousand's of rows and 100's of columns... and I cannot manually enter the formula.. In the demo data I have used the most common occurrences the data has...

This is my data

[image: This is my data]

This is what I want

[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a couple of VBA functions (below)
Use like following;

```
For 1st Start Date use the formula
 =GetStartDate(A2:E2,1)

For 2nd Start Date use the formula
 =GetStartDate(A2:E2,2)
```

Similarly for 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc use ,3  ,4  ,5 in the formula

Also for End Dates

```
For 1st End Date use the formula
 =GetEndDate(A2:E2,1)

For 2nd End Date use the formula
 =GetEndDate(A2:E2,2)
```

The VBA Functions are as follows

```
Public Function GetStartDate(SrcRng As Range, dIndex As Long) As Variant
   ' Parameters ...
   '  .. SrcRng - Range of Dates to Check
   '  .. dIndex ... 1 = Match to 1st Start Date, 2 = Match to 2nd Start Date, etc

   Dim xCel As Range, dCtr As Long, LastVal As String, StillChekin As Boolean

   GetStartDate = ""
   dCtr = 1
   LastVal = ""
   StillChekin = True

   For Each xCel In SrcRng.Cells
      If StillChekin Then
         If xCel.Value = "" Then
            If LastVal <> "" Then
               dCtr = dCtr + 1
            End If
         Else
            If dCtr = dIndex Then
               GetStartDate = xCel.Value
               StillChekin = False
            End If
         End If
         LastVal = Trim(CStr(xCel.Value))
      End If
   Next xCel
End Function

Public Function GetEndDate(SrcRng As Range, dIndex As Long) As Variant
   ' Parameters ...
   '  .. SrcRng - Range of Dates to Check
   '  .. dIndex ... 1 = Match to 1st End Date, 2 = Match to 2nd End Date, etc

   Dim xCel As Range, dCtr As Long, LastVal As Variant, StillChekin As Boolean

   GetEndDate = ""
   dCtr = 1
   LastVal = ""
   StillChekin = True

   For Each xCel In SrcRng.Cells
      If StillChekin Then
         If xCel.Value = "" Then
            If LastVal <> "" Then
               If dCtr = dIndex Then
                  GetEndDate = CDate(LastVal)
               End If
               dCtr = dCtr + 1
               If dCtr > dIndex Then
                  StillChekin = False
               End If
            End If
         Else
            If dCtr = dIndex Then
               If LastVal <> "" Then
                  GetEndDate = CDate(LastVal)
                  'StillChekin = False
               End If
            End If
         End If
         LastVal = Trim(CStr(xCel.Value))
      End If
   Next xCel
   If StillChekin Then
      If dCtr = dIndex Then
         If LastVal <> "" Then
            GetEndDate = CDate(LastVal)
         End If
      End If
   End If
End Function
```

Addendum for your comments question

Firstly you need to copy and paste the VBA code above into a new VBA Code Module in your Excel Workbook

Until you do that the Formulae will not work

So, Going by your "This is what I want" picture
 .. Looks like Column G is where you want the 1st Start Date
 .. and Column H is where you want the 1st End Date

Once you have the 2 new VBA functions you can enter the formulae like any other

Comment: Where do I use the formulas? and are there any changes to be made in the VBA?

Comment: Just appended answer to your comment at bottom of the answer

Comment: Alright that works!!.. Thank you..but like I said I would be having 1000's of columns and so changing the number in start date and end date would be time consuming.. any idea?

Comment: For 1,000's of rows and 100's of columns - raises a question of how many possible start and end dates there could be (hundreds clearly on any row) - think it's a bit beyond this forum for me to write and debug all that code for you, but you could try doing it yourself based on the answer given ... you have the basis of a solution there ... You need at least one more VBA Macro that calls the 2 existing, You also need to manage the data area and the Table of Start/End Dates ... a bit of work in that ... Thanks for the vote, but haven't the time to voluntarily complete the job for you

Comment: Take a stab at it yourself and come back for help if you need it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if there's something simpler, but you could use something like this for the first start date that basically finds the first non-blank value (that's an array formula, i.e. use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=INDEX(A2:F2,MIN(MATCH(0,--ISBLANK(A2:F2),0),5))
```

First end date (that's also an array formula) that basically finds the first blank value after the start date, and goes one cell back:

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,IFERROR(MATCH(G2,A2:F2,0)-1+MATCH(1,--ISBLANK(INDEX(A2:F2,1,MATCH(G2,A2:F2,0)):F2),0)-2,5))
```

Second start date, that basically goes 2 cells after the last end date, but if you can have more than one blank cell between non-blank cells, you might use something a bit more similar to the first formula for the start date:

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,MIN(MATCH(H2,A2:F2,0)+1,5))
```

Second end date (same as the previous end date array formula but with one adjusted reference for this one's start date):

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,IFERROR(MATCH(I2,A2:F2,0)-1+MATCH(1,--ISBLANK(INDEX(A2:F2,1,MATCH(I2,A2:F2,0)):F2),0)-2,5))
```

Rinse and repeat for the third start and end dates:

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(J2,A2:F2,0)+1,5),5))
=OFFSET(A2,0,IFERROR(MATCH(K2,A2:F2,0)-1+MATCH(1,--ISBLANK(INDEX(A2:F2,1,MATCH(K2,A2:F2,0)):F2),0)-2,5))
```

[image]

This kind of leaves `0`s out there, but you can use `IF( XXX = 0, "", XXX)` where `XXX` is the whole of the formula, it makes it prettier but more than twice as long of a formula.